# Box Drawing Characters and CLS in PHP CLI Mode

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm wondering if there's a way to display [Box-Drawing characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) in [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) (Command Line Interface) under MS-Windows (i.e. using `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f "myscript.php"`). Any attempt I've made shows up unreadable characters.
Furthermore I would like to know if there's a way to obtain a [CLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CLS_(command)) (clear screen) under [PHP CLI](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) under MS-Windows. I tried `system('cls')` and `exec('cmd /c cls')` without success.
All my attempts failed up to now.

Answer (score 0):

System calls are the most inefficient way of doing this, those often involve creating one or more processes. All you need to do is emit some [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), you just `echo` the right characters and you can do anything screen-wise.

What you probably want is [NCurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) which is a library that does things like drawing boxes, windows and so on.

Comment: it looks like windows is not supported [see](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ncurses.php).
Furthermore there's no ANSI escape sequence for CLS [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS).

Comment: That's unfortunate as curses is pretty portable. The `CLS` command moves the cursor to 1,1 (`CUP`) and then calls `ED` (Erase Display). There's no singular clear screen command, but that does the same thing. If you redirect the output of `CLS` to a file you'll see what it does.

Comment: despite the late hour in Italy, I'm playing around with it. It's really a pity it doesn't work under Win. :-(